# Почему не могу получить доступ к странице? requests

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет. Тренируюсь в написании парсеров, и мне попался интересный сайт: https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/
И я решил попробовать его спарсить с помощью requests|bs4
Немного покапавшись  я нашел нужный для меня запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я его отправляю:

```
session = requests.session()
ua = UserAgent()
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
}
session.headers = headers

session.get("https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/")
session.get("https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/search/index")
# тут я получаю токен от рукапча т.к. на сайте невидимая капча стоит
token = captcha_solution(session, "https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru")

data = {
    "mode":"onlyActual","filter":{"pledgor":{"privatePerson":{"lastName":"Иванов","firstName":"Иван","middleName":"","district":"","birthday":"","passport":""}}},"limit":"10","offset":"0"
}

headers = {
    "Host": "www.reestr-zalogov.ru",
    "Content-Length": "191",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Origin": "https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/search/index",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
}
session.headers = headers
r = session.post(f"https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/api/search/notary?token={token}", data=data)

print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

В ответ я получаю не нужный json а html страницу с надписью "Доступ запрещен". Что не так делаю, можете подсказать?

P.S с куками все норм.
Уже хз что делать.

Comment: Ну может оно куки ещё проверяет? Зайти на главную страницу сначала, сохранить куки....

Comment: в коде видно что я сначала захожу на главную страницу

Comment: таким образом получаю куки, эти куки сохраняются в сессию дальнейшую сессию я и использую

Comment: Ну тогда не знаю. Только отслеживать Fillder-ом все запросы и воспроизводить в точности. Не знаю.